# how to create table and send it to email in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a table for these strings and send it via email the problem is that these string are array which may have multiple values and i can't use loop inside string.

So Please help me how to solve it

Thanks in Advance

```
string CusID = Request["CusID"];
string[] Name = Request["Name"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string[] Code = Request["Code"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string SellDate = Request["SellDate"];
string[] SellQuantity = Request["SellQuantity"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string[] SellPrice = Request["SellPrice"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string[] Paid = Request["Paid"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string[] Status = Request["Status"].Split(char.Parse(","));
string[] Discount = Request["Discount"].Split(char.Parse(","));

for (int i = 0; i < Name.Length; i++)
{
   var totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(SellQuantity[i]) * (Convert.ToInt32(SellPrice[i]) - Convert.ToInt32(Discount[i]));
   var insert = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"insert into Details(CusID,Name,Code,SellDate,SellQuantity,SellPrice,Paid,[Status],Discount)
         Values({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{8},{9})", CusID, Name[i], Code[i], SellDate, SellQuantity[i], SellPrice[i], Paid[i], totalprice, Status[i],Discount[i]);
}

   try
   {
      MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
      mail.To.Add("aspmvcmail@gmail.com");
      mail.From = new MailAddress("abcdefghijklm@gmail.com");
      mail.Subject = "hi "+DateTime.Now;

      string Body = // store table in this string
      mail.Body = Body;
      mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
      SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
      smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //SMTP Server Address of gmail
      smtp.Port = 587;
      smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abcdefghijklm@gmail.com", "**********");
            // Smtp Email ID and Password For authentication
      smtp.EnableSsl = true;
      smtp.Send(mail);

      return Json("Your Message Send Successfully.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch
    {
       return Json("Error............", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: You need to create html table sing the loop. You can use the same loop, which you are using for performing databse operation, to create html table. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-dynamic-table-with-format-email-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks for your fast response i did but it says invalid expression term

Comment: Can you share that code and tell us which line gives what error?

Comment: Sorry for the first Comment The link worked thank you very much for such a great and fast response

Comment: now how to mark this as solved question